# Is it ok to use commas after a number written in digits?

Tags: commas, numbers

In [Dog-eating an exaggerated myth](http://www.stuff.co.nz/dominion-post/comment/letters-to-the-editor/10874121/Dog-eating-an-exaggerated-myth)

> I categorically state that [eating dogs] is not at all a widespread Swiss habit and that the 3 per cent (that would make 130,000 Kiwis) are totally made up.

the "Kiwis" is confusing - it looks as if the author meant there were 130,000 New Zealanders, or 130,000 Kiwi birds, whereas Kiwis are the people he's addressing, and I'd be tempted to put a comma in.

However, I can't recall seeing a number written in digits with a comma after it. Is it ok to use a comma after a number written in digits?

Comment: It's got bigger problems than the comma.

Comment: @HotLicks - the dogs, or the use of "are"?

Comment: He's not addressing Kiwis. So far as I can tell, he's saying 130,000 Kiwis would be 3% of all Kiwis, which seems right in line with a 2013 New Zealand population estimate.

Comment: Which is all well and good for the New Zealanders, but what about the Swiss and their *hundwurst*?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out who those 130,000 Kiwis made up with.  (And did they kiss when they did it?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reason why a comma should not be placed after a number in such a situation.

> We bought a pound of butter, a dozen eggs (that's 12, Mark) and a pint of milk.

makes sense assuming, perhaps facetiously,  Mark may not understand what a dozen means.

However this is not what is meant in the phrase

> that would make 130,000 Kiwis

The reference is to 3% of the population of Switzerland eating dogs. This applies to Switzerland (although it may not be true). What the writer means is that if this 3% applied to New Zealand then it would be 130,000 New Zealanders. 3% of the population of New Zealand is about 130,000. Switzerland has more people.

So what the writer means is that if the same proportion of Kiwis ate dogs, as it is suggested Swiss do, then that would be 130,000 New Zealanders.

If you look at the populations of New Zealand and Switzerland this corroborates the meaning.  It could have been written much more clearly.

Comment: I must be either innumerate or ignorant about geography! Sorry about that.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm But no one actually answered the question you raised.  I see nothing wrong with placing a comma after a number written in digits. If the number includes one or more delimiting commas, then it might be better to use a semi-colon to distinguish it from them.